# How to monitor all sdcard folders whose name contain a certain string like "download"?

Tags: java, android, file-io, android-sdcard

In my APP I want to monitor **all the sdcard folders** whose name contain "download", no matter in which level they are, if new file add to these folders, I want to notice myself.

The folder maybe in the sub directory of root path, or in a "child" directory.

From now I think of using "**FileObserver**", scan all the certain folders and set observer on them. but it's a huge amount of work. Can anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String sdCardState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
if( !sdCardState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED ) ) {
    displayMessage("No SD Card.");
    return;
} else {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    lookForDownloadDirectories(root);
}

// lookForDownloadDirectories() method:

public void lookForDownloadDirectories(File dir) {
    if( dir.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("download") ) {
        doSomethingWithDownloadDirectory(dir);
    }
    String[] filesAndDirectories = dir.list();
    for( String fileOrDirectory : filesAndDirectories) {
        File f = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileOrDirectory);
        if( f.isDirectory() ) {
            lookForDownloadDirectories(f);
        }
    } 
}
```

This is recursive method and as you know is time and resource consuming...

Comment: Thanks your timely answer, this recursive method is perfect, I'll try it, thanks

Comment: By the way, is the "FileObserver" my only choice?

Comment: My plan is using a "Service" to manage two "List", one is "folder" List another is "Observer" List.

Comment: Android Documentation: "Each FileObserver instance monitors a single file or directory. If a directory is monitored, events will be triggered for all files and subdirectories (recursively) inside the monitored directory." If you add a FileObserver on the root of your SD card, you will be notified on all files and folders events. I think this is not a good idea. You can run "lookForDownloadDirectories()" method on your app start up or running it in a thread in time intervals you prefer. I have a 16GB SD card and scanning this card takes less than 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad: Published reports indicate that the documentation is incorrect; `FileObserver` is not recursive.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend DirectoryWalker class from [org.apache.commons.io](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html) library.